# How to get the commit name where the introduction of PATTERN was made?

Tags: git

I remember I made some changes during a commit on a certain branch but I cannot find which one. I should have been more serious with my commits comments.

> So I am looking for where/when I first made a specific change like `s/foo/bar/`.

Fortunately I know what to search to find this commit and I can use `git grep` as follow:

```
git rev-list branch | xargs git grep --count --perl-regexp bar > changeset
```

The bad thing is that I'll get the name of all the commit after the one I am looking for.

In order to narrow down until THE commit where the change was made I found this ugly solution:

```
cat changeset | \
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^(.*?):/' | \
sort -u | \
perl -ne 'print qx{git show -s --format=%ci $_} =~ s/\n//gr, " $_"' | \
sort -u | \
head -n1
```

Which gives me the commit I am looking for:

```
2015-05-08 13:16:10 +0200 957d6d1c765862c8969230f8c6be4b663bcf7f01
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hi there. Not clear to me what you asking. you know that you have made a change and you want to find out when/where (commit &branch) the change was made? do you know at least one file name in this change?

Comment: Exactly and yes I know at least one file name in this change

Comment: Ok, then ill write you an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you know at least one file that was created/modified in the desired commit

> So I am looking for where/when I first made a specific change like s/foo/bar/

You can do any of the following to find out the desired commit

#### [`git bisect`](https://github.com/nirgeier/Tutorials-bisect)

git bisect will "loop" over all your commits in a given range and you can use it with the `-run` flag to automate the lookup process.

When using `git bisect --run` you specify a script that will "search" what that you wish to find.

[Here](https://github.com/nirgeier/Tutorials-bisect) you can clone a simply git repository, follow the instructions and you will **learn** what is `git bisect` in few minutes.

---

#### `git log --follow  <file>`

`--follow` the file that you search for in the history log.

Using the `--follow` flag will also track the file and all also old name(s) if the file was **renamed**.

This will print out the list of the commits which includes the desired file.

Use more flags for a better filtering your results (like `-m` for merges - since it was merged from another branch, `--stat` to "track" the changes etc)

---

#### `git log -- file1 file2 ...`

Instead of using the `--follow` flag you can simply track the file bu using the special `--` (2 dashes) after the log command and supply list of desired commits which include the file. Again use any more flags to make your output nicer

```
git log --stat --decorate --graph -- file1 file2 ...
```